# window.print() is not generating PDF and not making it downloadable when we open the website on phone in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdf-generation

I am using window.print() method in angular 2 to print my receipt(Invoice) window in the form of PDF, it is running very well on PC Browser, we can see the PDF as well as able to download it but the main problem is that the function is not running on phone's browsers , cant download or save the PDF.
Below is my downloadReceipt() method:

```
 downloadReciept(): void {
   var printContents, popupWin;
   printContents = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
   popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 
   'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=100%');
   popupWin.document.open();
   popupWin.document.write(`
       <html>
         <head>
         </head>

         <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents} 
         </body>
       </html>`
);
popupWin.document.getElementById('hidden').style.display='block';
popupWin.document.close();
this.loading = false;


     }
```

The main problem in it is not running on phone....please help , is there any other way to download the invoice or a html window in the form of PDF in angular 2 ??? Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

use this code mate

```
const printContent = document.getElementById("componentID");
const WindowPrt = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=900,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WindowPrt.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
WindowPrt.document.close();
WindowPrt.focus();
WindowPrt.print();
WindowPrt.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi This i have convert html to pdf using print option with custom size:

> 1. First off check jquery version may be latest version not support print: I have use `<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`
> 2. If you want pdf with canvas size use size property in print media option and also margin zero so heading and and page count hide  :

```
@media print { @page {   size:5.4cm 9.1cm; margin:0; 
page-break-after: auto;  }
```

> 3. Printable div should be give id = target_warpper1;
> 4. Also hide other element in js using css

**HTML:**

```
<div id="target_warpper1_print">
    <div class="visiting-card-right">
        <div class="visiting-card-up active">Employee Id</div>
        <div class="visiting-card-down active">
            <div class="visiting-card-logo"><img src="../images/visiting-card/logo.svg" alt="Vishal Korade Logo"></div>
            <div class="visiting-card-detail">
                <div class="visiting-card-name">Vishal Korade</div>
                <div class="visiting-card-designation">Front End Developer</div>
                <div class="visiting-card-txt visiting-card-email1"><span class="card-img"><img src="../images/visiting-card/mail.svg" alt="Vishal Korade Logo"></span><span class="crad-text visiting-card-email">janhavi.vishal@gmail.com</span></div>
                <div class="visiting-card-txt visiting-card-number1"><span class="card-img"><img src="../images/visiting-card/number.svg" alt="Vishal Korade Logo"></span><span class="crad-text visiting-card-number">9769367630</span></div>
                <div class="visiting-card-txt visiting-card-skype1"><span class="card-img"><img src="../images/visiting-card/skype.svg" alt="Vishal Korade Logo"></span><span class="crad-text visiting-card-skype">test</span></div>
                <div class="visiting-card-txt visiting-card-address1"><span class="card-img"><img src="../images/visiting-card/address.svg" alt="Vishal Korade Logo"></span><span class="crad-text visiting-card-address">7 Straits View Marina One East Tower, test, 66337</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="visiting-card-left">
        <div class="visiting-card-up"><img src="../images/logohome.png" alt="Vishal Korade Logo"></div>
        <div class="visiting-card-down"><img class="page-cover" src="../images/visiting-card/page-cover.svg" alt="Vishal Korade ID Page Cover"></div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="download-pdf" id="create_pdf" onclick="PrintElem()">Download as PDF</div>

JS:
function PrintElem(target_warpper1)
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=680,width=1200,toolbars=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,resizable=no');
   // mywindow.document.writeln('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
    mywindow.document.writeln('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">');
    mywindow.document.writeln('<style>');
    mywindow.document.writeln(' * { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;  color-adjust: exact !important;        }');
    mywindow.document.writeln(' body {background-color: #1f2959;}');
    mywindow.document.writeln('.card-left {background-color: #1f2959;float: left;}');
    mywindow.document.writeln('#target_warpper1 {display: block;width: 204px;padding-bottom: 0px;float: none;margin: 0 auto;}');
    mywindow.document.writeln('.visiting-card-right {width: 204px; float: none; margin: 0px auto; }');
    mywindow.document.writeln('.visiting-card-left { width: 204px;float: none; margin: 25px auto 0;}');
    mywindow.document.writeln('#target_warpper1_print { display: block;width: 204px;padding-bottom: 0px;margin-right:0px;float: none;margin: 0 auto; }');
    mywindow.document.writeln(' .visiting-card-up, .visiting-card-down::after, .visiting-card-down::before, .visiting-measure  { display:none;}');
    mywindow.document.writeln(' @media print { @page {   size:5.4cm 9.1cm; margin:0;  page-break-after: auto;  }  html, body {  height: 99%;} .print:last-child { page-break-after: auto;}  }');
    mywindow.document.writeln('</style>');
    mywindow.document.writeln(document.getElementById('target_warpper1').innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.writeln('</body></html>');
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/
    $(mywindow).load(function(){
       mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
    });
    return true;
}
```

if you need any additional information let me know.